# Error when i try to search in Datatable Yajra

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Code works fine but when i try to type any key for searching it showing up this errors :

Datatable Error

> DataTables warning: table id=my-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Request Error (Network):

> Status code: 404 Not Found

JS

```
jQuery('#my-table').dataTable({
        columnDefs: [],
        pageLength: 5,
        lengthMenu: [[5, 8, 15, 20], [5, 8, 15, 20]],
        autoWidth: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: true,
        ordering: true,
        ajax: "{{route('getdatatable')}}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'commande_num', name: 'commande_num'},
            {data: 'id_client', name: 'id_client'},
            {data: 'commande_quantity', name: 'commande_quantity'},
            {data: 'commande_montant', name: 'commande_montant'},
            {data: 'commande_date', name: 'commande_date'},
            {data: 'commande_date_retrait', name: 'commande_date_retrait'},
            {data: 'commande_paid', name: 'commande_paid'}
        ]
    });
```

HTML (Table)

```
<table id="my-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter ">
   <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">NO°</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center" style="width:10%;">Client</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center">Quantity</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center">Montant Total</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center">Date de Facture</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center">Date de Retrait</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center">Paiments</th>
          </tr>
    </thead></table>
```

BackEnd (laravel)

```
public function tableCommandes(){
    //commandes arrays
    $commandes=[];
    for ($i = 0 ;$i<7;$i++){

        $thisDay = DB::table('commandes')
            ->where("commande_date","=",Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->addDays($i))
            ->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->get();
        foreach ($thisDay as $item){
            array_push($commandes,$item);
        }
    }
    $collection = new Collection($commandes);
    return (new CollectionDataTable($collection))->make();
}
```

help please!

Comment: can you show the route('getdatatable')? did you check the link in the browser?

Comment: the link it's working fine and sometimes data shown in the table  and sometimes not with the both errors, even when it's displayed, when i type a character in search field or trying to change table length showing the same errors

Comment: I solved the error, the problem was `php artisan serve` i moved the project to the `wamp server folder` `wamp64\www` & set the `url` as `ajax : {{asset('/url')}}` and fixed the error

Comment: but you told me that your link is working fine..

Comment: anyway .. glad you solved it :) happy coding

Comment: yeah it was working for sometimes not always especially when i trying to search or changing table length, anyway thanks man:)